# Optimize C# code for counting number of occurences in nested loop

Tags: c#, optimization

I want to optimize this code for counting the number of occurrences in a list of strings. To be specific, I have two lists

1) `cat`: a huge list of string with duplicates (duplicates must exist).

2) `cat_unq`: the distinct elements from cat.

What I am currently doing in my code is looping all unique elements in `cat_unq` and counting how many times the unique element exists in the list of duplicates. The search runs on a mobile device.

I already tried switching to arrays from list but the performance was slightly better and not sufficient.

Another try was using parallel search using foreach parallel but the performance was not stable.

Here is the code I am currently using :

```
private List<int> GetCategoryCount(List<string> cat, List<string> cat_unq)
{
    List<int> cat_count = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < cat_unq.Count; i++)
        cat_count.Add(cat.Where(x => x.Equals(cat_unq[i])).Count());
    return cat_count;
}
```

Comment: Does `cat_unq` have all the unique values from `cat` or a subset?  If the former you can just do a grouping on `cat` and get the count of each occurance.  And even if it's the latter it would be better to get those counts in one pass of the `cat` list and then use it to get your counts in the desired order.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That wouldn't help much here since they iterate all the values in `cat_unq` and then iterate the values in `cat`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It depends.  Maybe `cat_unq` represents some type of desired order.  But really it almost sounds like they might be getting the distinct values up front and then doing this which is even more work than is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is slow because you are searching the entire `cat` array for every unique name. (`cat.Where(....).Count()`).

Instead, group your cat list with duplicates, and make it a dictionary. Then you can quickly find the number of each unique name.

```
private List<int> GetCategoryCount(List<string> cat, List<string> cat_unq)
{
    var catsDict = cat.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
    return cat_unq.Select(c => catsDict[c]).ToList();
}
```

Note that if you are elsewhere forming your uniqe list of cat names its pointless, you can do that all together in the above (The dictionary has the unique cat names as keys)

```
// No need for a separate list of unique names
private List<int> GetCategoryCount(List<string> cat)
{
    return cat.GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => g.Count()).ToList();
}
```

or maybe what you *actually* wanted was a list back of all the unique names *and* the counts

```
// No need for a separate list of unique names - as this one returns it with the counts in a dictionary
private Dictionary<string,int> GetCategoryCount(List<string> cat)
{
    return cat.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary((k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
}
```

Comment: One thing to note that this will be reasonably fast when categories in cat and can_unq are same-ey size. if cat_unq contains significantly less categories than cat_unq, then this might do lots of unecessary grouping. But I would recommend profiling for this kind of scenario.

Comment: @Euphoric yes (oh, and thanks for the edit!). Although we'd need to have a *lot* of cats for the extra cycles in grouping to make a difference.